# Having trouble uploading image to AWS s3 bucket with node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

i'm trying to upload an image to s3 using nodejs and aws sdk. It keeps returning a weird error: **"Inaccessible host: `images.dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the 'us-east-1' region**

This is my lambda code:

```
exports.handler = function(event,context,callback){
     var s3 = new AWS.S3();
     const image = event.body.imageBinary;

     var buf = new Buffer.from(image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64');
     const type = image.split(';')[0].split('/')[1];
     var params = {
          Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
          Key: `${AccountId}.${type}`, 
          Body: buf,
          ContentEncoding: 'base64',
          ContentType: `image/${type}`
      };

      s3.upload(params, function(err, resp){
          if (err) { 
             console.log(err);

          } else {
             console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!: ' + JSON.stringify(resp));

          }
      });
}
```

I even tried setting the AWS object configuration (with key, secret key and region) but got the same response

my aws sdk version: **"aws-sdk": "^2.610.0"**
Any help would be nice

Thanks!!!

Comment: Very odd. Are you 100% sure this is the code causing that error? Are you packaging and uploading the aws-sdk? Try without uploading it. The Lambda runtime contains aws-sdk (slightly earlier version but should suffice).

Comment: The word `images` should not be in the host name. It sounds like something related to your code.

Comment: looks like a DNS issue. Are you behind a firewall that could be preventing you from reaching `images.dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, the aws sdk is in the package, i even erased the node_modules folder and made npm install again and keep getting this error

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've changed that name multiple times and it throws the same error

Comment: @AmitNaik I've tried in multiple places whit differents connection providers and it doesn't work, what is weard to me is that it says this **Inaccessible host: `images.dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the 'us-east-1' region** but i'm not trying to connect to dynamo but to a S3 bucket

Comment: I'm saying *don't* include the aws-sdk in your upload package. Move it to your devDependencies. Leverage the aws-sdk that's already available for you in the Lambda runtime. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @AmitNaik there is no such thing as images.dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, afaik. The DynamoDB endpoints do not include images.*. That aside, this Lambda function is using S3, not DynamoDB.

Comment: Another option is to write a simple Lambda function within the Lambda console itself and have it exec s3.listBuckets (give the Lambda permission to do this) - this will remove your build/deployment tools from the picture completely. Test it, then use that same code from your dev environment and use your build/deploy tools to deploy it.

Comment: @jarmod tried that, but got the same error

Comment: Tried what? Writing a really basic version of the code in the us-east-1 Lambda console and running it there? I don't see how it's possible for that to cause this error. If you use the awscli, can you list S3 buckets? If not, what error do you see? BTW I tried this and it worked fine.

Comment: @jarmod worked with a simple lambda in the console! it's weard, but im going to upload the function with this simple code and then add the other stuff to see where it fails! thnx a lot for your help xD

Comment: I am guessing that you have something strange going on in either the parts of the code that we can't see or your local network/environment or in the way you package and deploy the code. Definitely provide an update when you find out what the root cause is, because the symptoms are unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda support node.js v12. Which allows you to write `async/await` code

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
});

exports.handler = async(event,context) => {
 const image = event.body.imageBinary;

 const buf = new Buffer.from(image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64');
 const type = image.split(';')[0].split('/')[1];

 var params = {
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
      Key: `${AccountId}.${type}`, 
      Body: buf,
  };

  const options = {
    ACL: 'private',
    CacheControl: 'max-age=86400',
    ContentType: `image/${type}`,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
  };

  await s3.upload(params, options).promise();
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer. It's a good idea, but it doesn't address the question.